# Bash script to get all file with desired extensions

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm trying to write a bash script that if I pass a text file containing some extension and a folder returns me an output file with the list of all files that match the desired extension, searching recursively in all sub-directories

the folder is my second parameter the extension list file my first parameter

I have tried:

```
for i in $1 ; do
   find . -name $2\*.$i -print>>result.txt
done
```

but doesn't work

Comment: "the folder is my first parameter the extension list file my second parameter" - the script seems to use the args the other way around.

Comment: There are so many errors... leave off the `[]`, leave off the `:` after `do`, and always put spaces between things, otherwise bash is gonna search for commands `for[` or `do:`, or give you `something]` as a variable value.

Comment: you are right I have corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted from in comment:

It is not a good idea to write to a hard coded file name.
The given example fixes only the given code from the OP question.
Yes of course, it is even better to call with

```
x.sh y . > blabla
```

and remove the filename from the script itself. But my intention is not to fix the question...

The following bash script, named as `x.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n >result.txt                             # delete old content
while read i; do                                # read a line from file
       find $2 -name \*.$i -print>>result.txt   # for every item do a find
done <$1                                        # read from file named with first arg from cmdline
```

with an text file named `y` with following content

```
txt
sh
```

and called with:

```
./x.sh y .
```

results in a file `result.txt` which contents is:

```
a.txt
b.txt
x.sh
```

OK, lets give some additional hints as got from comments:
If the results fiel should not collect any other conntent from other results of the script it can be simplified to:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read i; do                    # read a line from file
       find $2 -name \*.$i -print   # for every item do a find
done <$1 >result.txt                # read from file named with first arg from cmdline
```

And as already mentioned: 
The hard coded result.txt could be removed and the call can be something like

```
./x.sh y . > result.txt
```

Comment: Writing to a statically named file is a massive, anguish-filled antipattern. There is a reason Unix tools write to standard output; just follow their lead.

Comment: Fair enough. The `echo -n` is still completely superfluous; just redirect the `done` to overwrite any previous file. And maybe explain that this is not what you recommend.

Comment: @tripleee depends what you are doing.

Comment: You should still double-quote all variables which could contain a file name or file name fragment, and use `read -r` to disable the pesky legacy default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Give this one-liner command a try.

Replace **/mydir** with the folder to search.

Change the list of extensions passed as argument to the **egrep** command:

```
find /mydir -type f | egrep "[.]txt|[.]xml" >> result.txt
```

After the **egrep**, each extension should be separated with `|`.

`.` char must be escaped with `[.]`